# ¿Se puede instalar Node.js en un Servicio de Hosting compartido?

Tags: javascript, php, nodejs, aplicación-web

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Php pero necesito utilizar Node.js para agregar más funcionalidades al proyecto, pero este esta alojado en un servidor compartido,  y me surgió una duda ¿Se puede instalar Node.js en un servidor compartido? y si no es así como puedo trabajar utilizado Node.js para el proyecto en Php. 
Gracias

Comment: Para aclarar un poco, estás en un servidor (real | virtualizado) al hablar de servidor compartido, tienes acceso a la shell del sistema operativo del servidor o lo que tienes es hosting con su CPanel?

Comment: solamente es un hosting con su CPanel,

Comment: Ok, te respondo

Answer (score 2):

Dado que es un hosting con manejo limitado a CPanel y sin acceso a la shell del S.O. no es posible realizar una instalación de Node.  Incluso los mismos desarrolladores de CPanel informan de esto en el siguientes enlaces:

https://features.cpanel.net/topic/nodejs-hosting

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-can-i-install-node-js-on-cpanel.407341/

Te sugiero desplegar un servidor de tipo IaaS, siendo que Amazon Web Services otorga un año de uso gratuito en su versión mínimo o algún otro servicio como DigitalOcean, Linode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx es un servidor
web, al estilo de Apache
pero orientado a
eventos (como Node) y
actúa como un proxy lo
que nos permite
redireccionar el tráfico
entrante en función del
dominio de donde
vienen, hacia el
proceso y puerto que
nos interese.

Si deseas corre un aplicacion podria usarlo :)

Comment: https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/como-configurar-nginx-con-node-js-en-produccion/    para mas información :)

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta acerca del hosting compartido.

Answer (score 0):

En un servicio de hosting compartido, generalmente no se puede instalar nuevos programas (node.js por ejemplo), por lo cual te recomendaría que pruebes con los vps de amazon o digitalocean, en el cual tu tienes la administración del mismo.